# need that javascript function to only runs once

Tags: javascript

To go back in a page, we're using:

```
onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)"
```

Can we restrict consecutive clicks ?

Please suggest.

Comment: -1 for inline JavaScript, history object, not clear question. Please tell us what do you mean by "consecutive click".

Comment: i mean to not allow going further that two previous page and the button to not be consecutive clicked.

Comment: Use some internal logic, this question is to broad and yet somehow needs basic understanding in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use inline JavaScript. Not only it makes your code less maintainable but it makes attaching and detaching events much harder.

What you should do is to fetch the target element from the DOM and attach a click handler to it. To be able to detach it later, the click handler can't be an anonymous function, so define it separately.

Later on you can attach the listener that will be executed when you click the element. If you want to run it only once, you can use the click handler to detach the handler itself afterwards. See example (in the context of an event handler 'this' refers to the DOM element itself)

```
var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
var clickHandler = function(e) {
    alert("clicked");
    this.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
}
button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

Here's a working example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xAjnG/?editors=101

To extend it further, if you want the button to be active not once but a number of times, you can keep a counter. Note you can use this general case and set limit = 1.

```
var button = document.getElementById("clickme");
var counter = 0;
var limit = 3;
var clickHandler = function(e) {
alert("clicked " + ++counter);

    if(counter >= limit) {
        this.removeEventListener("click", clickHandler);
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

Here's a working example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzjcC/?editors=101

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the onclick attribute after it is clicked:

```
onclick="javascript:history.go(-1); this.onclick=null;"
```

Comment: He added this information right after I posted my answer. As I am not sure what he wants I will leave this answer as it "restricts consecutive clicks".

Comment: I mean restricting,not destroying, now if i click again i got null on the page